# get-childitem with -recurse causes -contains match to behave differently when comparing $GitStatus

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

Using posh-git in powershell I am able to list all the items in the working tree that have changed, by using the collection variable $GitStatus.Working, I can use this list in a where clause to filter a directory listing like so

```
dir | where {$GitStatus.Working -contains $_.Name}
```

this works really well to display all the files in the current directory that are altered but not yet in the index, however when I run this same command with the -recurse directive the file(s) no longer match. I don't understand why. Any ideas?

(Note Posh-GiTDir from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PromptsAndDirectoriesEvenBetterGitAndMercurialWithPowerShell.aspx) suffers from the same problem, not surprisingly as he uses basically the same technique, to show the "Git" column)

Edit: This started when I noticed that the Posh-GitDir Git column did not display anything when I did a recursive directory listing. It's useful to be able to quickly see what's changed "from this folder down", I looked at how Posh-GitDir gets its info to try and debug why it wasn't working for a recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using `$_.Name`, but when you do `git status`, which is what `$GitStatus` would give you from Posh-Git, it will give the directory and the file name. So when you are considering the current folder only ( `dir` without `-recurse` ) it works out find as it will only be the names. But when you consider files within directories, they will be relavtive paths and will not match with `$_.name`

And btw, `$GitStatus.Working` is SUPPOSED to show the files in the repo that are in working directory but not added. Why are you trying to get a list of all files and filtering it with the items from `$GitStatus.Working`

If you want FileInfo object from the `$GitStatus.Working`, try doing:

```
$GitStatus.Working | gi
```

**Edited to show the final solution based on this answer:** 
So for my purposes, what I did was....

```
$working = $GitStatus.Working | gi | %{$_.FullName}
dir -recurse | where {$working -contains $_.FullName}
```

(edited the edit, the previous snippet was not correct.)

Comment: That was my first thought as well. However the Name field does not appear to be relative with a -recurse (and yes I am aware that this is another problem...i.e. potential false positives)

Comment: @TimJarvis - Name property is just the name of the file yes, but $GitStatus.Working will give you `path/file1` and you are seeing if it has `file1`. So it will not work.

Comment: mmm, true. :-) now I am confused why it works when in the current directory. In this case I am comparing path/file with file as well. Surely neither should work. But it's got to be a path issue as I just noticed that if I change to the dir with the wrong case, that also breaks it. (posh-gitdir also has that problem)

Comment: Seems like what I need to do is get the output from the $GitStatus collections, pre-pend the drive:\gitdir and convert the / to \ then match on FullName....sound about right?

Comment: @TimJarvis - Hmmm, I donno what your exact case is, but note that `git status` give `dir1` if you create a new directory `dir1` with file `b`. It will not show `dir1/b`. See if this has any relevance. Also check my updated answer. Update your question with sample situation so that I can explain it.

Comment: @TimJarvis - See my updated answer- why are touching your nose around your head? :)

Comment: "touching my nose around my head" what the hell is that supposed to mean?  - I Updated my question.